# PhoneGap config.xml whitelist tel

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

OK, i know this question has been asked before but I cannot get it work. I have read doc after doc and read everyone of the stackoverflow questions related but I cannot get tel links to work on PhoneGap for Android. Below is the code that is being used.

```
<div data-role="content">              
    <h1><img src="img/comp-files/logo.png" /></h1>
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-icon="false" data-divider-theme="a" class="nightly-navigation">
        <li>
            <a href="tel:00-00-000-000"  data-rel="external">00-00-000-000</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My question is where should be config,xml file be? Currently I have 2 one on the directory that contains www, plugins, platforms, hooks, .cordova & another config.xml file that resides within in the www directory. Should there be 2 of these or only one, and where should it go?

Once that is figured out how should I configure this xml so that tel links work? Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="app.contractor.company" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>company Contractor App</name>
    <description>company application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="geo:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="sms:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="market:*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="geo:*" />
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="sms:*" />
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="market:*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />   
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please *answer the following questions in your post*. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001)? **NOTE** It appears you are using CLI, _please read link and confirm_. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your confg.xml which is located along with www, plugins, platforms, hooks folders as follows

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
```

Once you changed this it will copy the same thing in another config.xml file also.
and anchor tag as follows

```
Phone:<a href="tel:00-00-000-000"> 00-00-000-000 </a>
```

Hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

On the www folder you **only** store all your assests, such as html files, js files, css, etc. This is the folder that phonegap/cordova will use to create the assets to the different versions of the app (ios,android,etc)

So to answer your question, there should one config.xml on the folder that containes www,hooks,platforms,etc

When you build your projects, phonegap will create some copies of it inside each platform project, but it will be copies of the one located on the main project folder (the one that contains www,platforms,hooks,etc)

Hope it helps